# SELECT only returning 20 rows in 3rd party tool after inserting 100K rows via command line

Tags: oracle11g

I inserted 100,000 rows in a table via Oracle 11g CMD Interface and it returns 100,000 rows inserted. But when selecting data from the table using third party software PL/SQL developer tools it returns 20 rows.

How's that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Your Insert operation finish then try to commit it then apply select operation on that table.

Comment: why commit is require?

Comment: Commit means what ever transaction do force fully store to database from buffers. otherwise Oracle Command Line tools by default store data into buffer then buffer itself  write into database .

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how have you loaded your 100k rows into the table? What do you mean by "Oracle 11g CMD Interface" ? Have you used sql loader utility for oracle ?

Comment: Oracle CMD means oracle sql plus and load data 100k rows from main production database to dummy database.